# How do I cut a cylinder into a bunch of distinct pieces based on grid?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I am new to Blender and I’m working on a concept figure for a project.

I am trying to take a cylinder, put a 10x10 grid on the top face, and cut the cylinder into a bunch of pieces based on the downward extrusion of that grid. The goal is to change the material properties of each part of the cylinder. The cylinder represents a laser for context. How would I go about doing this? Thanks, any help is appreciated.

Comment: do you have a reference image of what you want? Maybe the Knife Project tool is what you need, you can project a grid onto the top face then extrude

Answer (score 2):

It would perhaps be easier to split one end of your cylinder in the flat, while <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>M</kbd> ***Mesh > Split > Faces by Edges*** still does the right thing, and *then* extrude it to form the composite solid.. (or use an *Edge Split* and/or a *Solidify* modifier):

[image]

Comment: How did you do that last part where you scale it and introduce spaces between the parts?

Comment: Hi, @Randalox! That bit was really just for illustration.. the steps are P > Separate by Loose Parts,  Object > Origin >  Origin to Geometry, and set the Object Mode 'Options' in the header to Transfrom: Affect Only > Locations. Then a Scale in XY (S Shift-Z) in Object Mode will spread the parts' locations without scaling their meshes. You could use that as a modelling tool, by Ctrl-J joining all the objects back together again, and resetting the origin to something sensible.